# Recorrer arreglo bidimensional PHP

Tags: php, array

Necesito recorrer un arreglo `$data` que es el siguiente:

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#18 (4) { 
        ["Descripción"]=> string(5) "Aceite"
        ["Codigo"]=> string(7) "2222222" 
        ["Precio"]=> string(2) "45" 
        ["Eliminar"]=> string(9) " Eliminar" 
    }
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#19 (4) { 
        ["Descripción"]=> string(4) "Caja" 
        ["Codigo"]=> string(7) "1111111" 
        ["Precio"]=> string(2) "50"
        ["Eliminar"]=> string(9) " Eliminar" 
    } 
}
```

Actualmente tengo el siguiente `for` que me da error, que no puedo acceder a los datos

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($data) {
    $datos['codigo']      = $repuesto->codigo;
    $datos['descripcion'] = $repuesto->Descripcion;
    $datos['valor']       = $repuesto->Precio;
    $datos['token']       = $this->funciones->RandomCaracteres(49);
    }
```

¿Cómo accedo a los datos del arreglo ?

Comment: Qué error te da?

Comment: ¿Qué es $repuesto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero que todo, tienes un error en tu ciclo `for` de sintáxis y te falta pasarle un último párametro de como va a aumentar tu contador (`$i`)

```
// Te faltaba esto           |______|
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
//                           |______|
}
```

Segundo, ¿de donde sale la variable `$repuesto`?

Tercero, te sería mucho más útil utilizar un ciclo `foreach` como explico en los siguientes pasos

Teniendo tu arreglo llamado `$data`

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#18 (4) { 
        ["Descripción"]=> string(5) "Aceite"
        ["Codigo"]=> string(7) "2222222" 
        ["Precio"]=> string(2) "45" 
        ["Eliminar"]=> string(9) " Eliminar" 
    }
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#19 (4) { 
        ["Descripción"]=> string(4) "Caja" 
        ["Codigo"]=> string(7) "1111111" 
        ["Precio"]=> string(2) "50"
        ["Eliminar"]=> string(9) " Eliminar" 
    } 
}
```

Puedes acceder a los valores mediante un ciclo `foreach`, donde `$data` es el arreglo a recorrer `$key` vendría siendo el indice de cada arreglo dentro del arreglo y `$val` vendría siendo el objeto de tipo `stdClass` como tal, entonces:

```
foreach($data as $key => $val){
    $val->Descripcion; // Aceite, Caja
    $val->Codigo;      // 2222222, 1111111
    $val->Precio;      // 45, 50
    $val->Eliminar;    // Eliminar, Eliminar
}
```